# AWS lambda times out when called by Step Function, or scheduled event. How to avoid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a lambda function that calls an external API (which takes more than 30 seconds) and returns data. Based on the step function docs, I thought that I could avoid the lambda timeout limit of 30 seconds by calling the lambda function through a scheduled cloudwatch event. That doesn't seem to be the case. How can I call a long running lambda function? I've tried:

1. calling the lambda function by invoking the CLI on my machine `aws lambda invoke...` **TIMES OUT**
2. calling the step function (which calls lambda) by invoking the CLI on my machine `aws stepfunctions start-execution...` **TIMES OUT**
3. running the function directly from my computer (not using lambda). Takes approx 45 seconds for api to respond. **WORKS**

Comment: Lambda execution limit is 15 minutes... Just change the execution duration limit?

Comment: yes, but the api gateway limit is 30 seconds. Is there a way to do this without going through the gateway?

Comment: Outbound request shouldn’t be going via API Gateway... Is the request that triggers the Lambda coming via API Gateway?

Comment: @hephalump you were correct. That fixed the issue. If you want to propose that as a solution I will accept... never occurred to me that outbound requests didnt go through the gateway

Comment: Awesome! Glad your issue was resolved and I was able to assist!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) the function timeout limit on a Lambda functions is 900 seconds / 15 minutes.

To resolve your issue, extend the function timeout limit on your Lambda function to the required duration.